# Как просчитать количество товаров WooCommerce WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wp-query

Хочу просчитать количество товаров на странице категории с определенным атрибутом.
Чтобы если количество товаров больше нуля, то показывать фильтр по категории

```
// получаем ID категории
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
echo $cateID;


// получаем товары нужной категории с нужным атрибутом
$product_cats = new WP_Query;

// делаем запрос
$productcats = $product_cats->query( array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'cat' => $cateID,

     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'tax_query' => array(
            'meta_key' => 'pa_vysota-podema-mm'
        )
    ) );
    
    $products = wc_get_products($productcats);

if($products > 0) : ?>
    
//тут код фильтра по атрибуту

 <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил этот вопрос так:

```
$args_vysoty = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $cateID
    ),
   array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_vysota-podema-mm',
        'operator' => EXISTS

    ))
);

$query_vysoty = new WP_Query($args_vysoty);

     <?php if($product_vysoty && $query_vysoty->post_count > 0) : ?>
        <div class="filter-product__area filter-product__area-5">
            <div class="filter-product__area-5-text filter-product__area-text">Высота <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                <div class="filter-product__area-5-popup filter-product__area-popup">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($product_vysoty as $product_vysot) :?>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" <?php if( isset( $_GET[ 'pa_vysota-podema-mm' ] ) && $product_vysot->slug == $_GET[ 'pa_vysota-podema-mm' ] ) : ?>checked<?php endif; ?> name="pa_vysota-podema-mm" value="<?php echo $product_vysot->slug?>"><?php echo $product_vysot-> name ?> (<?php echo $product_vysot->count ?>)</label></li>
        
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" class="" value="Применить">  
        </div>
    </div>
      <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас получится массив продуктов в строке `$products = wc_get_products($productcats);`, то вы можете подсчитать количество элементов в нём с помощью функции `count()`. То есть получится примерно следующее

```
<? if (count($products) > 0) : ?>
//здесь код фильтра по атрибуту
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Звучит логично, но всё-таки не работает)

Comment: А что лежит в `$products` по итогу?